# Macro to Analyze and Evaluate a String with respect to Data in different cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of “Data Codes” in - Column A, "Conditions” in - Column B and Numeric Values in “Column C”. I’m in need of a VBA code which verifies the condition in column B with respect to Data codes in column A and if the condition is true then update Column D with same values as column C or else put zero in Column D and repeat this process until the last data cell in Column A. I came across VBA RegEx, but I don't really know how can I use it to solve the problem?

Any Help is appreciated!

Example:-
Data Codes in Cell `"A1" = "AAA BBB DDD EEE GGG HHH A11 B11 C11 1A1 1AB AA0"`

Condition in Cell `"B1" = "( AAA + BBB + ( CCC | DDD ) + ( EEE + ! FFF ) ) | ( GGG + HHH + DDD + EEE + FFF )"`

Value in Cell `"C1" = "5"`

The Macro shall update Cell `"D1" = "5"` - Since the condition is true - “A1” has `AAA, BBB, DDD, EEE and "NOT FFF"`

Data Codes in Cell `"A2" = "AAA BBB DDD EEE GGG HHH A11 B11 C11 1A1 1AB AA0"`
Condition in Cell `"B1" = "( AAA + BBB + ( CCC | DDD ) + ( ! EEE + ! FFF ) ) | ( GGG + HHH + DDD + EEE + FFF )"`
Value in Cell `"C2" = "3"`
The Macro shall update Cell `"D2" = "0"`, Since the condition is false - “A1” has `"EEE"` and doesn’t have `"FFF"`

Comment: So you're working on assessing if the `Cells(i,1).Value`, split into an array based on " ", to see if any of those values are captured in `Cells(i,2).Value`?  Or are you wanting to ensure that all are found?  As this is tied to VBA, what *have* you put together (you talk about `regex` but have no attempt at using it in your post)?  Remembering that this is not a code-for-you service and is not the appropriate forum for a discussion, conversation, please provide your code so a specific, objective answer can be provided to an exact and specific question which you are asking.

Comment: Hi, you should show what you have tried so far, so that others may assist you.

Comment: It seems it might be helpful to organize your conditions a bit better. I have code that seems like I could modify it to suit your need, but I need a much better understanding of what you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO. Thanks and congratulation  for a good question.  There may be other parsing method for converting the condition string as workable formula, I opted for a simple parsing method and somehow out way approach to use the formula in VBA itself. Solution needs Reference  to "Microsoft Visual Basic for extensibility" … to be added (in VBA Project window  -> Tools-> Reference –> and then add).

It is assumed the conditions in column B is consistent and single space is between all the operators. However code could be modified for little changes in condition syntax. Sheet name, Row & Column details may please be modified for actual requirement.

The tested code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test3()
Dim TestStr As String
Dim CondStr As String, xFormula As String, iFormula As String
Dim Arr As Variant, VBstr As String
Dim i As Integer, Srw As Long, Lrw As Long, Rw As Long
Dim Ws As Worksheet, Wb As Workbook, Rslt As Boolean, vbc As VBComponent
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Set Wb = Workbooks.Add
Set vbc = Wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)

Srw = 1
Lrw = Ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For Rw = Srw To Lrw
'TestStr = "AAA BBB DDD EEE GGG HHH A11 B11 C11 1A1 1AB AA0"
'TestStr = "AAA BBB EEE GGG HHH A11 B11 C11 1A1 1AB AA0"
TestStr = Ws.Cells(Rw, 1).Value

'CondStr = "( AAA + BBB + ( CCC | DDD ) + ( EEE + ! FFF ) ) | ( GGG + HHH + DDD + EEE + FFF )"
CondStr = Ws.Cells(Rw, 2).Value

Arr = Split(CondStr, " ")
VBstr = ""
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
    xFormula = Trim(Arr(i))
    Select Case xFormula
    Case ""
    iFormula = ""
    Case "(", ")"
    iFormula = Arr(i)
    Case "+"
    iFormula = " And "
    Case "|"
    iFormula = " OR "
    Case "!"
    iFormula = " Not "
    Case Else
    iFormula = (InStr(1, TestStr, xFormula) > 0)
    End Select
    VBstr = VBstr & iFormula
    Next i
VBstr = "X = " & VBstr
Debug.Print Rw & VBstr


Dim StrLine As Long, LineCnt As Long
With vbc.CodeModule
On Error Resume Next
StrLine = .ProcBodyLine("VersatileCode", vbext_pk_Proc)
LineCnt = .ProcCountLines("VersatileCode", vbext_pk_Proc)
.DeleteLines StrLine, LineCnt
On Error GoTo 0
.InsertLines StrLine + 1, "Sub VersatileCode()"
.InsertLines StrLine + 2, VBstr
.InsertLines StrLine + 3, "ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).cells(1,1).value = X"
.InsertLines StrLine + 4, "End Sub"
End With
DoEvents
Application.Run Wb.Name & "!VersatileCode"
DoEvents

Rslt = Wb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value
Debug.Print Rslt

    If Rslt = True Then
    Ws.Cells(Rw, 4).Value = Ws.Cells(Rw, 3).Value
    Else
    Ws.Cells(Rw, 4).Value = 0
    End If
Next Rw
Wb.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much "Ahmed AU" for the solution! We were trying create a code with State machine looking for each and every character and then deciding the logic, but it was getting a bit complicated because of lots of possible combinations. I really liked your approach of  making the decision based on Boolean data. Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome, You made my day.  Hope for success..

Comment: Please refer to @Tim Williams [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57311216/is-vba-compilation-of-changing-code-is-responsible-for-wrong-results-in-a-loop/57315422#57315422) to my question for his brilliant & further improved solution..

Comment: Thank you very much Tim Williams and @Ahmed AU for taking time and providing the solution. It took a while for me to understand what's code since I'm new to this stuff.